# How do I make sure that my app showing in tablet store

Tags: java, android, google-play, user-permissions

In my app I play some music and as any other music apps, I should stop music when the user receive a call, so, I use this permission for that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I use the permission for control the telephony manager.

I know some tablets devices doesn't have phone feature so for that Google Play Store filtered my app, it considered it as an app compatible only with devices which is contains phone feature.

With some search I edited my code:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

And in MainAcitivty :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)) {
                checkPermission();
                if (!checkPermission()) {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }
        }
```

My Question: after this edit, will my app show up in tablets store or should I should do something else?

Answer (score 0):

This might be enough, but you should make sure you are following all the [Tablet app quality guidelines](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality.html).